# how to search pattern with numerals in vim

Tags: regex, search, vim

I want to search for all patterns with completely matching string part but some numerals.

Example I have a file containing

```
foo_1
foo_2
foo_3
foo_33
foo_34
foo_35
foo_65
foo_66
foo_67
```

and so on and I want to search only `foo_2` , `foo_34`, `foo_66`

```
/foo_[2|34|66]
```

This doesn't return me desired search. Can help here?

Comment: (with very magica)l -- `/\vfoo_(2|34|66)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/foo_\(2\|34\|66\)$`.

See section 27.5 in the vim help for details.

Comment: `/foo_\(2\|34\|66\)` also returns me `foo_204`, any way to limit it?

Comment: Yes, add `$` at the end of the pattern.